# Angularjs ui-router state not working when new nested state added

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I m new to angularjs and ui-router...I m facing hard time in solving issue
I have ui router configured.It works well upto two nested states but when i add new  nested state ,it stop working.i cant figure out the reason,can some one point me what i miss??

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        templateUrl: 'public1/settings.html'
    })
    .state('settings.profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: 'public1/profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileController'
    })
    .state('settings.account', {
        url: '/account',
        templateUrl: 'public1/account.html',
        controller: 'AccountController'
    });

    .state('settings.login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'public1/login.html'

    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/public1/profile');});
```

Comment: Any error in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

The end of your settings.account 'state', you have a semi-colon before the .state('settings.login ...

That's what's causing your error, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **";"** from account state

```
.state('settings.account', {
            url: '/account',
            templateUrl: 'public1/account.html',
            controller: 'AccountController'
        })

        .state('settings.login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'public1/login.html'

        });
```